# What is a simple way to estimate $σ_{RV}$ assuming photon noise in radial velocity measurements?

Tags: astrophysics, measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis, exoplanets

Hello there i have been trying to figure out what is wanted in the question "Simple way to estimate σ_RV assuming photon noise" for a presentation. But i can not seems to find much, but i have a suspicion that it is related to these pp-slides. I feel relatively certain that δN_(Ph) is the change in photon counts as the counts recieved changes as the radial velocity changes times the dopler shift. And the N^(1/2)_(Ph) is just the count uncertainty assuming Poisson distribution.

What I am unsure about is what δv_(min) actually means is it the uncertainty in the RV or the minimum measurable RV? and is it even related to the uncertainty?

[image]

[image]